# Kotlin 1.4.30 Apache beam compilation error

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-beam, compatibility

I was trying to update to latest kotlin verion 1.4.30 an Apache Beam dataflow pipeline that is currently running with kotlin 1.4.21 but as soon as I upgrade build.gradle with version 1.4.30 the compilation fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read class: VirtualFile: /Users/stefanomassera/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-core/2.26.0/b57f8fa5ae66564c7ffafde34b690057f471bfa8/beam-sdks-java-core-2.26.0.jar!/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions.class
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(KotlinCliJavaFileManagerImpl.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.KotlinJavaPsiFacade$CliFinder.findClass(KotlinJavaPsiFacade.java:484)
  ... omissis for brevity
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wildcard mast have a bound for annotation of WILDCARD_BOUND position
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaAnnotation$Companion.computeTargetType$resolution_common_jvm(Annotations.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.AnnotationsAndParameterCollectorMethodVisitor.visitTypeAnnotation$getTargetType(Annotations.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.AnnotationsAndParameterCollectorMethodVisitor.visitTypeAnnotation(Annotations.kt:117)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1427)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:719)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:402)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.classFiles.BinaryJavaClass.<init>(BinaryJavaClass.kt:115)
    ... 101 more
```

I've also tried with a blank dummy project just to verify if it is a compatibility error with current kotlin and apache beam and it seems a compatibility issue, here my dummy test

main.kt

```
package org.example

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory

class DummyPipeline {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(*args)
            .withValidation()
            .`as`(DummyPipelineOptions::class.java)
        val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)
        pipeline.run()
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.30' //<-- do not build
    //id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.21' // <-- correctly build
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.26.0"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.26.0"
}
```

Did anyone solved this compatibility issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've experienced the same issue today, but even reverting to the previous version of Kotlin doesn't help

Comment: nope I've also asked in Kotlin #datascience and #kotlin-beam slack channel but still no response

I was forced to revert both Gradle AND Intellij Kotlin plugin to 1.4.21 in order to fix the problem also plugin contributes to build failure

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It causes by the Kotlin compiler.

Sorry for nuisance, I'm currently fixing that on the compiler's side. The fix will be available in Kotlin 1.5-M1.

Unfortunately, there are no normal workarounds here, since the problem occurs when reading class files (it's impossible to exclude the problematic logic in the mechanism for reading class files).

Comment: Is there a link to the issue for tracking? Has this been released already?

Comment: The issue is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45067